# Excel función BuscarX() por columnas

Tags: excel

Tengo que usar la función buscarX() para buscar en una tabla aparte
un codigo y donde esta ese codigo en esa misma columna abajo del todo en verde traerme ese valor a otra tabala, donde indico en la foto 2, la cosa es que la función trabaja en filas y devuelve los valores de la fila donde encuentra la coincdencia del código, y yo necesito la columna.

[image: Tabla donde busco]

[image]

[image: Tabla donde recibo los datos buscados].com/HQ6wI.png

Comment: Las funciones BuscarV y BuscarH están mejoradas y se eliminan muchas de sus deficiencias con INDICE - COINCIDIR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo con SUMAPRODUCTO:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La tabla de la izquierda, donde están los datos a sumar, la he llamado `Tabla1`. Y la de la derecha, donde obtienes el resultado, sería `Tabla 2`. Fíjate que ese total que estás obteniendo, que está fuera de la tabla, en realidad es una suma de la columna de ese código (que podrías sacar activando fila totales, no necesitas hacerlo aparte).

Mi fórmula es la siguiente:

```
=SUMAPRODUCTO(Tabla1[[67]:[106]]*--(VALOR(Tabla1[[#Encabezados];[67]:[106]])=[@CÓDIGO]))
```

Y ya ves que trae justo lo que necesitas

Comment: Hola, muchísimas gracias, entiendo la función SumaProducto pero despues lo de valor que has puesto comentado nose como aplicarlo a la fórmula SumaProducto, para que efectivamente sume la columna que coincida con el código

Comment: La fórmula ya hace la suma de la columna que coincida con el código.

Comment: Vale ya va bien, muchas gracias, 2 preguntas:  esto asi ( asterisco -- ) que significa no lo habia visto nunca antes, y la segunda si por ejemplo en tu tabla1 agrego un nuevo codigo (107) en la columna D, como podría hacer para que en mi tabla2 el rango de la fórmula se actualice automáticamente sin tener que modificar el rango yo a mano , =SUMAPRODUCTO(Tabla1[[67]:[**107**]]*--(VALOR(Tabla1[[#Encabezados];[67]:[**107**]])=[@CÓDIGO]))

Comment: @Chupitastiiks El asterisco es para multiplicar. El `--` se llama operador doble unario y sirve para transformar una matriz booleana en matriz de 1 y 0. Lo de agregar un nuevo código, si lo agregas al final, tienes que actualizar a mano, el rango no se actualizará solo. Si lo agregas entre medias, sí se actualizará solo

Comment: muchísimas gracias!! Ya lo tengo todo solucionado.